# Read MINC (mnc) file

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej, minc

I want to read a .mnc file I've downloaded from http://brainweb.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/brainweb/.
This file contains simulated data of MRI scanning of a human brain. What I want is, to read the file using java code and convert it into buffer image object so that I can process buffer image object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bio-Formats [can read MINC MRI](http://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/bio-formats5/formats/minc-mri.html) files.
Use [`BF.openImagePlus(String path)`](http://ci.openmicroscopy.org/job/BIOFORMATS-5.0-latest/javadoc/index.html?loci/plugins/BF.html) to open the file as an [`ImagePlus`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/ImagePlus.html):

```
ImagePlus imp = BF.openImagePlus(path);
```

You can then use ImageJ to work with the pixel data (i.e. using an [`ImageProcessor`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/process/ImageProcessor.html) or, if necessary, a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)).